# Why Deployment Descriptor: Archetype Created Web Application, appears in every packages in SpringMVC package?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, eclipse, hibernate, spring-mvc

[image: you can see the "Why Deployment Descriptor: Archetype Created Web Application" in every folder]

im learning SpringMVC, and find this problem, project running well, but this is irritating

Answer (score 0):

I think the web.xml is in wrong place

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

this line in web.xml is giving error.

Answer (score 0):

you just have to delete these lines from the file "web.xml"

```
<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```